# How to read this txt file by the german weather authorities?

Tags: r, data.table, read.table

Any ideas of how to read this txt-file properly?
ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/hourly/wind/recent/FF_Stundenwerte_Beschreibung_Stationen.txt

I used `read.fwf` but this is not working propperly. Also `fread` failed.
Here's my code so far:

```
width <- c(0, 11, 21, 31, 45, 56, 66, 107, 150) # Looked it up in Excel :)
width <- diff(width)
url <- "ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/hourly/wind/recent/FF_Stundenwerte_Beschreibung_Stationen.txt"
con <- url(url, encoding="Latin1") # I am user Ubuntu

col.names <- c("station_id", "von_datum", "bis_datum",
                 "stationshoehe", "geoBreite", "geoLaenge",
                 "stationsname", "bundesland")

dat <- read.fwf(con, width, skip = 2, na.strings="\032",
                    strip.white = TRUE,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                    col.names = col.names)

dat <- dat[-nrow(dat), ] # The last row only has this na.strings="\32"
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem with your code? It seems to read the data just fine.

Comment: There is no "problem" with the code. It just seems very complicated . And i wanto know wheater there is an obvious and simpler way.  

I want to read in similar files as this one:
ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/observations_germany/climate/hourly/cloudiness/recent/N_Stundenwerte_Beschreibung_Stationen.txt

But it seems a huge overhead to write the width, col.names and colClasses myself every time

Answer (score 1):

ooops- I see there are some whitespaces in the 7th column, so the typical approach is to read the entire file in via `rawfile<-readLines(your_file.txt)`, then do  `fixfile<-gsub('[ ]{1,}/)',')',rawfile)` to eliminate the unwanted spaces , and then separate  the data by whitespace (`strsplit`) , and finally convert columns 1 thru 6  from `character` to `numeric` .

If it weren't for those few whitespaces before parenthesis, you could use `read.table` or other `base` file input tools which treat any collection of white-space as a delimiter and dump your data directly into a matrix for you.   Perhaps you'd find it easier to download the file, run it thru a text editor, then load into `R`.   It's kinda up to you :-)

edit: alternatively, if you don't need the names in parenthesis, `gsub('[(].*?[)]','',rawfile)` could be done.